# How do I configure what effect I want on a Panel expand/collapse event?

Tags: extjs

In ExtJS 2.2.1, is there a way to configure what effect gets used when animCollapse=true on a Panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try suggestion at: [the Ext Forum](http://extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=43702).

```
animCollapse : Boolean/Mixed
```

False (default) to skip the animation, otherwise specify a valid Ext.fx method: 'blind' (the current effect), 'fadeIn', 'fadeOut', ...etc).

I think Ext Js topics are highly specialized, and the Ext JS Community Forums are the best place for getting your question answered.

Comment: Good answer.  But I actually would prefer ExtJs questions were asked and answered here - better, faster UI and a more pleasant community IMHO

Comment: Yes, I agree. It would be great if Ext JS adopted StackOverflow model or even better if they moved their support to SO.

Comment: I agree - I posted the question here because I believe StackOverflow is the best knowledge management system out there.  I am learning, and learning to love ExtJS, but their support forums are not very usable compared to StackOverflow.  If the people who monitor their forum (great people, great advice) were to use this tool instead, they would be way more effective, and ExtJS might even gain market share.

Comment: This Q & A is a perfect example of what I mean when I say the standard forum approach used by ExtJS is not as effective as StackOverflow.  I spent a good deal of time searching their forums before posting here.  I got results here extremely fast.  Check out this video that explains why Joel would say that StackOverflow presents a better community support option than forums.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWHfY_lvKIQ